# Prove or disprove the following inequality: $1- a \cdot f_k - \sum_{i=1}^n f_k p^i \leq (1-af_kp)^n$

Tags: inequality, markov-chains

When solving a problem in Markov chains, I was faced with the task of proving if the following inequality is true or not
$$
1 - a\cdot f_k - \sum_{i=1}^n f_kp^i \leq (1-af_kp)^n , \ \forall n\in \mathbb N
$$

Note that $a\in \mathbb N$ and $f_k, p \in (0,1)$. Can anyone help me check if this inequality is true or not? Bonus: if the inequality is not true, is there a $\beta \in (0,1)$ for which

$$
1 - a\cdot f_k - \sum_{i=1}^n f_kp^i \leq \beta ^n , \ \forall n\in \mathbb N
$$

Comment: Have you tried binomial theorem: $(1-af_kp)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}(-1)^i(af_kp)^i$

Comment: Yes, but I got lost trying to analyze how the terms would prove the inequality. Perhaps the Binomial theorem is indeed the way to go and I just couldn't work out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of many counterexamples, if
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
n=2,\;\;\;
a=3,\;\;\;
p=\frac{3}{4},\;\;\;
f_k=\frac{1}{28}
$$
then$\;\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}={\Large{\frac{3}{12544}}} > 0$.

As regards the bonus question, for fixed $a,p$, choose $f_k\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
f_k < \min
\Bigl(
\frac{1}{2a},
\frac{1-p}{2p}
\Bigr)
$$
Then we have
$$
af_k < \frac{1}{2}\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;f_k\Bigl(\frac{p}{1-p}\Bigr) < \frac{1}{2}
$$
hence there is no $\beta\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
1-af_k-\sum_{i=1}^n f_kp^i \le \beta^n
$$
for all $n$, since as $n$ approaches infinity the $\text{LHS}$ approaches
$$
1-af_k-f_k\Bigl(\frac{p}{1-p}\Bigr) > 1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} = 0
$$
whereas $\beta^n$ approaches $0$.